# from css to tailwind concersion of "vw" and "50%" for full with image inside a flow

Tags: tailwind-css

I would like to reproduce in tailwind : https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/xOjaYA
Especially this part of the code :

```
.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

If you have `mode: 'jit'` enabled in your **tailwind.config.js**, you can use whatever css you want without config changes.

For example:
`className="m-[-50vw] w-[100vw]"`

More details: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Answer (score 2):

Here it is https://play.tailwindcss.com/EHQk10LYK8

The only thing missed in "original" Tailwind is negative half of viewport width margin so I've added it into config

```
theme: {
  extend: {
    margin: {
      '-half-screen': '-50vw',
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So only option is to Add in config right? I guess this will help others as it's a quit "commun" issue.

Comment: you see another way of achieving this with tailwind or this solution is the best one for this case?

Comment: If there are no some options in Tailwind, the only way to add it - via tailwind.config.js. Same for extending or overwriting options which exists. In your case 50% and 50vw are not the same so the only "Tailwind-way" is to add it.